# Fast Cross Table Update with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, query-optimization

Simple question :D. I know how to do it, but I have to do it fast.

What’s the most time efficient method?

Scenario: two tables, `tableA` and `tableB`, update `tableA.columnA` from `tableB.columnB`, based on `tableA.primarykey = tableB.primarykey`.

Problem: `tableA` and `tableB` are over 10.000.000 records each.

Answer (score 8):

```
update TableA as a
    join TableB as b on
        a.PrimaryKey = b.PrimaryKey
set a.ColumnA = b.ColumnB
```

Updating 10 million rows cannot be fast. Well... at least in comparison to the update of one row.

The best you can do:

- indexes on joining fields, but you've got this, as these fields are primary keys
- limit by `where` condition if applicable. Index covering where condition is needed to speed it up.

Comment: That's pretty much _the_ answer.  If it's not fast enough for you, you probably need better indexing and/or faster hardware.